# React bootstrap form textarea row height

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to get my text area to display with row height recognition. I've followed several of the suggestions that have been made on this board.

I currently import componentClass from react-bootstrap and in my form field, I have:

```
<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor="overview">Outline your proposal</label>
  <Field
    name="overview"
    componentClass="textarea"
    rows={4}
    className={
      "form-control" +
      (errors.overview && touched.overview ? " is-invalid" : "")
    }
  />
  <ErrorMessage name="overview" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
</div>
```

It still renders in a single line.

What is the hidden secret about making this work with row numbers for text area?

Comment: What is `Field`?

Comment: a Formik element.

Comment: thank you: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1237